# JPA query for a JSONB column in Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to create a query with JPA for a JSONB column in a Postgres DB. The query will pretty much look like this example from the [Postgres JSON Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html):

```
-- Find documents in which the key "company" has value "Magnafone"
SELECT jdoc->'guid', jdoc->'name' FROM api WHERE jdoc @> '{"company": "Magnafone"}';
```

where `jdoc` is the JSONB column in table `api`.

So far executing this query is easy and not a problem. However if I try to parameterize the query I'm stuck.

Here are a few queries I've tried:

1) This does not work, because the ? is not recognized between the '-signs:

```
String name= "Magnafone";

JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SELECT jdoc FROM api
WHERE jdoc @> '{\"name\": ?}'", Record.class)
.setParameter(1, name)
```

Error:

```
    play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal p
arameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:
2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:
2.2.3]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordin
al parameters are 1-based! Position: 2
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:451) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at models.lol.player.IPlayer.getPlayerByName(IPlayer.java:22) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.LoadTeamController.loadTeamData(LoadTeamController.java:23) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position:
 2
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Fina
l]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Fi
nal]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:445) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]</code>
```

2) I've found this in another SO-Thread. Does not work though, because the || shows up in the query and throws an SQL Exception.

```
JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SELECT jdoc FROM api 
WHERE jdoc @> '{\"name\": ' || :name ||'}'", Record.class)
.setParameter("name", name)
```

Error:

```
    play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal p
arameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:
2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:
2.2.3]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordin
al parameters are 1-based! Position: 2
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:451) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at models.lol.player.IPlayer.getPlayerByName(IPlayer.java:22) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.LoadTeamController.loadTeamData(LoadTeamController.java:23) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position:
 2
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Fina
l]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Fi
nal]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:422) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:445) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
```

I've tried a few other things that made Postgres or JPA throw up in one or another way and didn't manage to get the JSON Parameter while using the parameterization from JPA.

3)

```
JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SELECT jdoc FROM api 
WHERE jdoc @> '{\"name\": ' || ? ||'}'", Record.class)
.setParameter(1", name)
```

Error:

```
    play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: FEHLER: ung³ltige Eingabesyntax f³r Typ json
  Detail: Die Eingabezeichenkette endete unerwartet.
  Position: 62
  Where: JSON-Daten, Zeile 1: {"name": ]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:
2.2.3]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:
2.2.3]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: FEHLER: ung³ltige Eingabesyntax f³r Typ json
  Detail: Die Eingabezeichenkette endete unerwartet.
  Position: 62
  Where: JSON-Daten, Zeile 1: {"name":
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:266) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at models.lol.player.IPlayer.getPlayerByName(IPlayer.java:24) ~[na:na]
        at controllers.LoadTeamController.loadTeamData(LoadTeamController.java:23) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: FEHLER: ung³ltige Eingabesyntax f³r Typ json
  Detail: Die Eingabezeichenkette endete unerwartet.
  Position: 62
  Where: JSON-Daten, Zeile 1: {"name":
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final
]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.
Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-4.
1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar:4.1.8.Final]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: ung³ltige Eingabesyntax f³r Typ json
  Detail: Die Eingabezeichenkette endete unerwartet.
  Position: 62
  Where: JSON-Daten, Zeile 1: {"name":
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157) ~[postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886) ~[postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555) ~[postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417) ~[postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:302) ~[postgresql-9.2-1003-jdbc4.jar:na]
```

FYI: This works (don't worry, I'm not using it):

```
JPA.em().createNativeQuery("SELECT jdoc->'guid', jdoc->'name' FROM api 
WHERE jdoc @> '{\"company\": \""+company+"\"}'", Record.class)
```

Also: I'm using the `createNativeQuery` because the `@>`-Operator is not recognized by JPA.

Thanks.

Timo

Comment: Try the `||` approach, but it should be something like `'{\"company\": \"' || ? || '\"}'`. Of course, use `setParameter(1, company)`.

Comment: Doesn't work either :/ He complains about the "-symbol. If i try `'{\"company\": ' || ? || '}'` the error says that the input string ends unexpectedly.

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the actual error messages - with full stack traces if available - to your question under each attempted option. By the way, you don't seem to close the string with `"` in any of your examples above. Is this the actual code you tried?

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste error. I'll fix it. Not the code exactly I'm using. I'll post the exact error messages soon.

Comment: Added the stracktrace.

Comment: Try `"... WHERE jdoc @> cast('{\"company\":' || to_json(cast(? as text)) || '}' as json)"` (or `jsonb` at the last cast, if that's appropriate).

Comment: Thanks pozs. That worked! If you'd post this as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pozs posted the Answer as a comment:

> Try "... WHERE jdoc @> cast('{\"company\":' || to_json(cast(? as text)) || '}' as json)" (or jsonb at the last cast, if that's appropriate).